# Ruby on Rails: How do I write a migration to add a reference to a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have

```
add_column :foos, :bar_id, :integer
```

but I wast to be able to do stuff like

```
@foo.bar.name
```

rather than

```
Bar.find(@foo.bar_id)
```

I think its done with t.references when creating a table... but how do a add it post-table-creating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit corresponding *model* file and add there for example `belongs_to` declaration. This is exactly what allows you to call the `@foo.bar.name`.

Answer (score 2):

see migration guide [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).

```
create_table :products do |t|
  t.references :category
end
```

That lets you specify it in the migration, but you also need to use *belongs_to*, and either *has_one* or *has_many* attributes in the model.  You could really do that without the migration to create it since you already have the foreign key id already setup.  Just use the above mentioned attributes.

Also see this [ActiveRecord guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to do that in a migration?  Why can't you just add the bar_id field in the migration, than add an association in foo's model?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Rails 4.x you can now generate migrations with references, like this:

> rails generate migration AddUserRefToProducts user:references

like you can see on [rails guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)